# How to get jQuery and ModelValidation in sync with correct UIculture?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, jquery-validate, globalization

I am working on an application intended for Croatian firm. culture info is: hr-HR
in my web.config i have set:

```
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" 
                   requestEncoding="utf-8" 
                   responseEncoding="utf-8" 
                   culture="hr-HR" 
                   uiCulture="hr-HR" />
```

And the values for, lets say decimal numbers are displayed correctly, that is in correct format that uses comma as decimal separator. 22,50 is hr-HR equivalent for en-US 22.50

My problem is, that jQuery validation still requires me to type in 22.50 for it to be recognized as decimal number, and if i do so then in the value does not get parsed as a decimal and the model is not valid in application.

My question is, is there a simple way to switch jQuery to certain culture for validation? Without implementing the internationalization and so on.

For now, i can solve the problem by reading FormCollection values, and parsing them manually, but that is not really a nice solution. I can also set the whole application to en-US culture but that also is not really a solution, just a fix.

Thank You

Comment: I know of no solution. The only problem I had was with decimal separator, so I just modified jquery.validate.js to allow both `.` and `,` for the separator

Comment: haha, that one i like for the decimals, what about the dates? currency?

Comment: As for the dates, the jquery UI calendar plugin supports globalization. But, as I said, this way you'll have to address each globalization problem separately

Comment: I have changed the `,` and `.` for the number rule. Now i am having problems with the range when the decimals are in play. Can you point me to where to alter jQuery validate to make it parse the values sent from application correctly?

Comment: I never altered the range rule. If you have floating-point values, you'll probably have to modify `range`, `min` and `max` rules as well, and maybe some more. Or opt for jquery.glob

Comment: Damn, i figured as much. I cant seem to find the decimals in range, min and max rules.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at jQuery-Glob?

https://github.com/nje/jquery-glob/

Comment: I have, and it seems a bit of an overkill to use whole globalization pack when all i need is to tell jquery to use certain culture always.
The jQuery-Globalize usage means a lot more code to write every time i have a decimal or date or currency field, or i have something wrong on how to use it for my problem?